# The name 'ResolveUrl' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

i am using asp.net framework 4 and i have created brand new project and below is the code and when i compile the proj i get this below errors... i have already spent good amount of time but not sure whats going on here...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace aspnet_membership_proj
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MyBaseMasterPage
    {
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl myJs = new HtmlGenericControl();
            myJs.TagName = "script";
            myJs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            myJs.Attributes.Add("language", "javascript"); //don't need it usually but for cross browser.
            myJs.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JScript.js"));
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(myJs); 
        }
    }
}
```

errors:

```
The name 'ResolveUrl' does not exist in the current context

'aspnet_membership_proj.SiteMaster' does not contain a definition for 'Page' and no extension method 'Page' accepting a first argument of type 'aspnet_membership_proj.SiteMaster' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What does `MyBaseMasterPage` look like? Does `MyBaseMasterPage` inherit from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`?

Comment: What does the MyBaseMasterPage class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your MyBaseMasterPage class. That is where the problem lies.
Also, Make sure that your MyBaseMasterPage class derives from System.Web.UI.MasterPage.